# SnackBar does not show second time jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to understand why my SnackBar does not show second time, I'm propagating the snackbar message and error boolean values from my composables, I'm taking this data and emiting a single snackbar but it works first time and not second time with the same message even if I set the message to null.

When I go to my register screen I emit an error message if the e-mail is already present in the DB, then if I trigger again the same message, nothing happens and the snackbar does not appear, any ideas ?

### MainActivity

```
setContent {
var snackBarMessage: String? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
            var isError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }


            CryptoTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                    snackbarHost = {
                        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState) { data ->
                            Snackbar(
                                snackbarData = data,
                                backgroundColor = if (!isError) GreenProfit else Color.Red,
                                contentColor = Color.White
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    bottomBar = { BottomBarNavigation(navController = navController) },
                    backgroundColor = Color.Black
                ) {
                    NavigationGraph(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = it.calculateBottomPadding()),
                        navController = navController,
                        showSnackBarMessage = { message, showError ->
                            isError = showError
                            snackBarMessage = message
                        }
                    )

                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = snackBarMessage) {
                        if (snackBarMessage != null) {
                            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                                message = snackBarMessage ?: ""
                            )
                            snackBarMessage = null
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Inside NavigationGraph I have multiple composables that reuse this way of propagating the message and error to the scaffold to show the snackbar

### NavigationGraph

```
NavigationGraph(showSnackBarMessage: (message: String, isError: Boolean)) {
Navhost(...) {
 composable(route) {
  RegisterComposable(showSnackBarMessage)
 }
}
```

and from the composable

### RegisterComposable

```
RegisterComposable(showSnackBarMessage: (message: String, isError: Boolean)){ 
 when(uiState.signUpError) {
  showSnackBarMessage("E-mail already in use", true)
 }
```

Comment: did you find out why this is happening? Im currently facing the same issue but im using compose for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/4070) in `kotlinx-coroutines:1.8.0-RC` you can simply fix it by upgrading to `1.8.0-RC2`.

If you are using **Compose multiplatform** it is fixed in version `1.6.0-beta01` of the compose plugin or you can downgrade to `1.5.11` where the issue does not happen.

Answer (score -1):

Your snackbar is not shown because the `message` and `isError` are not changed. Compose will only get recomposed when its referenced values have changed.

Snackbar is a kind of one-time event. So you need to provide it as an effect

Recommend: combine your `message` and `isError` into a data model

```
data class SnackBarAction(
    val uid: Long = System.currentTimeMillis(),
    val text: String,
    val isError: Boolean,
)
```

On your compose layout

```
val (stateOfSnackBarAction, setSnackBarAction) = remember {
    mutableStateOf<SnackBarAction?>(null)
}
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Scaffold(scaffoldState = scaffoldState) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = stateOfSnackBarAction) {
        stateOfSnackBarAction ?: return@LaunchedEffect
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
            message = stateOfSnackBarAction.text,
            backgroundColor = if (stateOfSnackBarAction.isError)  Color.Red else GreenProfit,
        )
        ...
    }
    ...
```

To show snackbar

```
Button(
    onClick = {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val current = System.currentTimeMillis()
            setSnackBarAction(SnackBarAction(
                uid = current,
                text = "Your message here",
                isError = true/false
            ))
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think, the explanation is right here